# Concept of virtual destructor

Tags: c++

I am confused about virtual *destructor*. I know if we create instance of derived class using a base class pointer like the following

```
Base *p = new Derived;
```

But if we delete this now

```
delete p;
```

Why would it not delete the object properly? What is `p` pointing towards ? I know that making the base class *destructor* virtual would kill the object properly but how does this thing conceptually work ? It has something to do with heap ? As a result of the statement

```
Base *p = new Derived;
```

What is being stored in the stack and what's on the heap ? And by simply deleting (with non virtual base destructor) why it's not calling the derived destructor. I'm just confused conceptually.

Comment: _'It has something to do with heap ?'_ No, it has to do with the class' vtable!